# How is it possible that I am overriding this code - css and html?

Tags: html, css

How can this below be possible, I don't understand, I get the same effect when clicked :active when removing this part from the first line of code not the bottom ", #cracker1-button a:active" and when keeping it. How is it possible that the " , #cracker1-button" overrides this at top?

```
#cracker1-button a:link, #cracker1-button a:visited, #cracker1-button a:hover, #cracker1-button a:active{
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #000;
}

#cracker1-button a:active{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Care to be more specific?  It's not clear to me what you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I praise you. Lets see... "#cracker1-button a:active" when it gets removed from the first part of the top code it does not effect the bottom part of the code. Which you can see in the window above.
How can it be possible that still when the "button" gets clicked the text inside the button becomes white even though I in the top part of the code I did tell it that when clicked - be black? How is that possible? When it actually shouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the two CSS selectors:

```
..., #cracker1-button a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

#cracker1-button a:active {
    color: #fff;
}
```

The second, and more recent, one will always overwrite the first. This is because both selectors have the same weight, and CSS will always use the most recent selector with the greatest (or equal) weight.

Comment: But I've always thought the the CSS which is higher up is more prioritized. Is that wrong? Or this this something specific with pseudo thingies?

Comment: The CSS selector which was written most recently is what gets used, as long as it has equal or greater weight.